# How to get a pdf Book cover display as a card image before viewing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, pdf

I want to display pdf book covers as an image before a user views a book. So basically a user will see a book image cover like this: [image] before viewing like this: [image]

I tries looking it up here:

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "before the user views the book"? Let the display pdf start at page 1 where that cover is?

Comment: Yes, the display starts at page 1 but I just want to display a cover page of the book before the user tabs or clicks on the book to view it.

Comment: use that cover page as the link to the book?

Comment: Yes Stefan, that's exactly what I need..